# Finding nfa or dfa for a language

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm trying to study for the summer ahead of class I saw this question, please how do I go about it?

Find NFA/DFA for the language $L = \{0^n1^n : n \in N\}$

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? What have you read? Where did you get stuck? Are you sure that DFA/NFA will be able to solve this?

Comment: Probably a trick exercise. Did you already read about the pumping lemma? Then try to apply it to show that $L$ is not regular.

Answer (score 4):

That language is not regular, thus no finite automaton, be it a DFA, NFA or εNFA, is sufficiently powerful to express it.

To express this language, you'll need a context-free grammar, a push down automaton, or a Turing machine.

Answer (score 1):

This language has infinite index, thus needs an infinite number of states according to the Myhill–Nerode theorem. You can't have a finite state automaton for it.

Comment: This answer is correct, but somebody who can't instantly recognize that $\{0^n1^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is non-regular probably doesn't know enough to use Myhill-Nerode.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, but it does give something OP can look into or further inquire about

Comment: @AMomchilov sounds like you are thinking of some other definition of index. Just read this: http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d25559k/ENGS122_files/Lectures_Notes/Henzinger-Nerode-7.pdf

Comment: I note that you are trying to help people -- that's great, thanks! However, you may want to be aware of our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) that cover many standard problems; there is often no need to give the same answer an upteenth time.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution guys, I clearly have a lot more to study